# Bind text from value in RowEditing

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I am implementing a RowEditing functionality

Here is one of the grid column

```
header: 'City', dataIndex: 'City_id',
editor: {
  xtype: 'combobox',
  queryMode: 'local',
  displayField: 'text',
  valueField: 'value',
  store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['text', 'value'],
    data: [
        { text: 'Atlanta', value: '1' },
        { text: 'New York', value: '2' }
    ]
  })
}
```

Stored procedure returns only city Id, that is 1 or 2. Now because I used " dataIndex: 'City_id' " at the header - only 1 or 2 is binding to the grid.

My question here is, in this I want to bind text not value to the display. How can I do this? Please suggest me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you would use a renderer on the column to display the text instead of the value.

Something along the lines of:

```
renderer:function(value) {
    return this.editor.store.findRecord("value",value).get("text");
}
```

Comment: But still it is rendering City_Id as header text.

Comment: @user1893874 [Since ExtJS4.0, the `header` config is deprecated](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.2-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-header) in favor of `text`, and I guess it has been subsequently removed from the source code.

Answer (score 0):

@Alexander's answer is the right way to go for updating the displayed value in the column.

To fix the issue with the column header, use the `text` property, not the `header` property, in the first line of your code sample.

Column config:

```
{ text: 'City', // NOT header: 'City' 
  dataIndex: 'City_id',
  editor: {
    ...
  }
}
```